# python import from string

Tags: python, string, import

I'm trying to import another python script with a name of the form `fe_fi_fo_fam.py`, I'm using `importlib.import_module("fe_fi_fo_fam.py")` but I'm getting the error : `"module fe not found"` , how do I get it to read the whole string instead of only the first part? I'm new to python and I seem to have scoured the internet without an answer.

Comment: Can't reproduce this problem. I get the error message `ImportError: No module named fe_fi_fo_fam`

Comment: Try `r"fe_fi_fo_fam.py"`.

Comment: What's wrong with `import fe_fi_fo_fam`?

Comment: Note that you specify the name of the module, not the name of the file. Don't include the `.py` since not all modules are in `.py` files.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can instead use the built-in function `exec` after you compose the module string

```
    >>> modOs = 'os'
    >>> exec('import ' + modOs)
    >>> os.getcwd()
    'C:\\Desktop'
```

Note: Python 3.6 [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

Comment: Considering that the purpose of `importlib` is to avoid shenanigans like that... please don't.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was an usual import, but your comment about the trailing `.py` might be the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to understand the difference between module name in Python and file name. importlib.import_module() gets a "module name", not a "file name", so "fe_fi_fo_fam.py" is not a valid argument, instead you have to use "fe_fi_fo_fam" with no .py extension.